# Designing ADC(AD9253) PCB Board with Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, adc, altium, layout

I am almost first time designing the PCB board with Altium Designer.
I've recently designed PCB Layout of ADC data acquisition circuit board.

The ADC is AD9253 from analog devices, 4-channel 80 MSPS/105 MSPS/125 MSPS sampling rate with Serial LVDS outputs.
My PCB consists of several SMA connectors for Analog inputs and clock input, AD9253 device, FMC LPC connector for connecting my board to the FPGA board.

AD9253 DataSheet  - https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9253.pdf

[The intention of the PCB board I made]

[image]

-Power input(5V) comes in by the pin header(J1).

-The 4 channel Analog inputs come from the SMA connector(J2,J3,J4,J5) to ADC input pins.

-There is External Clock input also comes from the SMA connector(J6).

-The digital outputs(LVDS) comes out from the ADC, and goes to both the pin headers(P2,P3) on the top layer and the FMC Connector on the bottom layer.

-The FPGA will read the digital output data connected by the FMC Connector.
(I'm thinking of reading the data through the pin header(P2,P3) in case of unconnection between fpga and fmc connector.)

-This PCB is 8-layer and consists of TOP/GND/PWR/GND/GND/PWR/GND/BOTTOM.

-PWR is connected by the pin headers(J11,J12) on the top layer.

To design this board, I referred to the design of EVAL-AD9253

- https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/ad9253-125ebz_ad9633-125ebz

My questions are
:

1. The width of the track is all the same with 10 mil, but is there a need to make the track width around the power or near the analog input or clock input especially thicker?
2. Do I really need to use the 8-layer to design this kind of board? I designed the 8-layer first, just referring to the gerber file and the schematics of EVAL-AD9253.

3.[image: Watching the FMC connector from the bottom side]

This is the FMC Connector on the bottom layer to connect with the FPGA board.
To connect the digital output and GND to the fmc pin, the vias are placed and the traces are
little bit complicated I think. I wonder if it's right to connect GND using the via on the FMC
connector.

4. Or are there any other strange stuffs in my pcb design? If you have any further questions, I
   would appreciate it if you could ask me additional questions.

Once again, I'm a beginner in PCB design, so I didn't design it all by myself, but I referenced the scheme and gerber of EVAL-AD9253 a lot.
I'll always be waiting for your response.
Thank you!